# Better Object destructuring in react and es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have an object with some properties like

```
weather.name = 'Coudy'
weather.country= 'USA'
```

Currently I am using Object destructuring in ES6 but as you can see it is quite verbose.
I would like to know if it is possible to rewrite in a more concise way this code.

Notes: I am using babel with

```
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-2"]
```

---

```
const Weather = ({ weather }) => {
  let {
    name,
    country,
    temperature,
    temperatureMin,
    temperatureMax,
    weatherMain,
    weatherDescription,
    weatherIcon,
    updatedTime,
    windDegree,
    windSpeed,
    visibility
 } = weather
  return (<div>
    { name }, { country }
    { temperature }
    { temperatureMin }
    { temperatureMax }
    { weatherMain }
    { weatherDescription }
    { weatherIcon }
    { updatedTime }
    { windDegree }
    { windSpeed }
    { visibility }
  </div>
  )
}

export default Weather
```

Comment: you want to print all the value of weather object or some specific one ?

Comment: what about `({ weather }) => (<div> { Object.values(weather).join("\n") } </div>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with parameter destructuring. `weather` temporary variable can be efficiently skipped (and `Weather` too - it isn't a constructor anyway):

```
export default ({ weather: {
    name,
    country,
    temperature,
    temperatureMin,
    temperatureMax,
    weatherMain,
    weatherDescription,
    weatherIcon,
    updatedTime,
    windDegree,
    windSpeed,
    visibility
 } }) => (<div>
    { name }, { country }
    { temperature }
    { temperatureMin }
    { temperatureMax }
    { weatherMain }
    { weatherDescription }
    { weatherIcon }
    { updatedTime }
    { windDegree }
    { windSpeed }
    { visibility }
  </div>)
```

All property names still should be written twice during destructuring, and this is a good thing here. This allows to pick only known properties from the object. If some of the used props weren't destructured or were misspelled in returned value, an error will be thrown. And if some of destructured props weren't used by accident, this can be indicated by IDE or a linter.

Comment: i think all the values will be `undefined` because they exist in `props.weather` not directly inside `props` ? he is `destructuring` twice.

Comment: Yes, it appears that you're right. Thanks for pointing at that.

Answer (score 0):

This is unsafe because it uses `eval` function, but you can do something like this:

```
const Weather = ({ weather }) => {
  eval(
    "var " +
    Object
      .keys(weather)
      .map(key => key + "="+ JSON.stringify(weather[key]))
      .join(', '));

  return (<div>
          {name}, {location}, 
          {anyAttribute.join(', ')}
  </div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Weather weather={{
    name: "lalala",
    location: "dadada",
    anyAttribute: [1,2,3]}} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: It should be noticed that `eval` makes possible the usage of `with`, which makes the thing simpler. But yes, `eval` is evil, and `with` isn't very kind, too.